# Carrying a sum forward as new spreadsheet is created

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet that I am trying to manipulate data on.  I have a Master spreadsheet, and once a week, it is duplicated and renamed, by the week.  An example of this would be Sept 8-12 2014 and then the next would be Sept 13-21 2014.  I have the sheet set to do a sum of each row, and put the total in the second last column.  In the last column, I would like to do a grand running total for the year.

So, if for example my column that totalled everything was AC, and the last one was AD, is there a way that I can set my spreadsheet to pull the data from AD of the last sheet, and then continuing summing up the total on the new current sheet after the Master spreadsheet is duplicated and renamed each week?

Thank you,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can [reference](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/75943?hl=en) data from other sheets. You may have to change what sheet it references every time you duplicate though.

Alternatively, with appscript, you can use the [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets()) method to get every sheet. Then you can [pull](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetValues(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) whatever necessary cell data from each sheet.

Comment: Okay, the getSheets() method seems to be the way to go.  Thank you for that. Quick question though.  Is there a way to exclude a few specific sheets, like the Master one or say one called Summary from the data collection?